# how to set default value for select statement

Tags: mysql

I have this quires but the default value is showing null.

```
SELECT c.course_id, 
       cast(AVG(fb.course_rate) as decimal(2,1)), 
       cast(AVG(fb.difficult) as decimal(2,1)),
       course_code,
       date, 
       course_col, 
       course_level, 
       course_name 
FROM course AS c 
LEFT JOIN course_feedback AS fb
  ON fb.course_id = c.course_id 
Where course_code LIKE '%$course_code%'  
GROUP BY c.course_id"
```

I need to set the default value 0 for the column

```
cast(AVG(fb.course_rate) as decimal(2,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have `NULL` values in the `fb.course_rate` column. You can use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to handle them

```
SELECT c.course_id, 
       cast(COALESCE(AVG(fb.course_rate), 0) as decimal(2,1)), 
       cast(AVG(fb.difficult) as decimal(2,1)),
       course_code,
       date, 
       course_col, 
       course_level, 
       course_name 
FROM course AS c 
LEFT JOIN course_feedback AS fb
  ON fb.course_id = c.course_id 
Where course_code LIKE '%$course_code%'  
GROUP BY c.course_id"
```